# Regular Expression to match between quotes only if also contains /

Tags: regex

I am trying to help someone clean up a bunch of anchor tags. Originally the relative paths used a bunch of sub directories and now they have moved all the files into a single directory, but now need to clean up the links by removing all references to sub directories from them. There are thousands of files to modify and I am trying to write a reliable regular expression that will clean them up.

Below is an example of the types of lines I am coming across and having trouble writing something that will work for all types.

Starting:

```
<a href="Choosefile.html">Choosing a File Type</a>
<a href="Deletefiles.html">Deleting a File</a><br /><a href="Exporting_a_File/Exportwindow.html"> 
<a href="Importing_a_File/Importwindow.html">
<a href="Searching/Searching_for_a_File/Searchpanel.html">
```

Goal:

```
<a href="Choosefile.html">Choosing a File Type</a>
<a href="Deletefiles.html">Deleting a File</a><br /><a href="Exportwindow.html"> 
<a href="Importwindow.html">
<a href="Searchpanel.html">
```

Currently I have the below expression, but when there are more than one anchor tag on the same line it doesn't work.

```
(?<=href\=([\"'])).*(?<=[a-z])(?:\\|\/)(?=[a-z])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your data is consistent, you may use

```
\shref=(["'])\K(?:(?!\1).)*/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iXR0cv/2) (note `/` might need escaping, it depends on where you are using the regex).

- `\s` - matches a whitespace
- `href=` - a `href=` substring
- `(["'])` - a `'` or `"` quote (Group 1)
- `\K` - omit the text matched so far
- `(?:(?!\1).)*` - any zero or more chars other than `'` or `"` (the value depends on what was captured into Group 1)
- `/`  - a `/` char.

Comment: Thank you Wiktor. That worked. Just for everyone else, the regex included in the linked regex demo is    \shref=["']\K[^'"]*/   which I think works a bit better.

Comment: It is V2 actually. I updated the link to the latest regex version.